# removing consecutive duplicates from the string

Tags: java, string, duplicates

Given a string S, remove consecutive duplicates from it recursively.

```
public class Solution {

    public static String removeConsecutiveDuplicates(String s) {
        // Write your code here

      if(s.length() <= 1)
      {
        return s;
      }
      String ans = "" + s.charAt(0);

      if(ans.charAt(ans.length()-1)!=s.charAt(0))
      {
        ans= ans + s.charAt(0) + removeConsecutiveDuplicates(s.substring(1));
      }
      //ans = ans + s.charAt(0)+
      removeConsecutiveDuplicates(s.substring(1));
      return ans;
    }
}
```

Why is this code wrong?
Although I've done this with a different method as well, I want to know why the above approach fails.

```
    **String ans="";
          if(s.charAt(0)==s.charAt(1))
          {
           ans = removeConsecutiveDuplicates(s.substring(1)); 
          }
          else
            ans = ans + s.charAt(0) + removeConsecutiveDuplicates(s.substring(1));
        return ans;**
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
if(ans.charAt(ans.length()-1)!=s.charAt(0))
```

will always be **false**, since `ans.charAt(ans.length()-1)` always contains the same value as `s.charAt(0)`, since the previous statement is:

```
String ans=""+s.charAt(0);
```

Therefore the statement

```
ans= ans + s.charAt(0)+removeConsecutiveDuplicates(s.substring(1));
```

is never executed. And even if it was executed, it would have resulted in wrong output, since you would have added `s.charAt(0)` twice to the output `String`.